# Python Moviepy installation problems (windows 7x64)

Tags: python-3.x, moviepy

Good day, i have a problem with instalation moviepy for python 64 bit and windows 64 bit.

Library was succesfully installed, file ffmpeg downloaded.

Every time i run it or using

```
video = VideoFileClip("path") 

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not valid win32 application.
```

How can this be solved? 
Imagemagick and PIL are already installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 # moviepy.__version__=='0.2.3.5'
```

solved following next steps :

1) manual download following instructions here [adaptivesamples.com/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-windows](http://adaptivesamples.com/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-windows);

2) disable autodownloading in `/site-packages/moviepy/editor.py` line 25:

```
if False: #os.getenv('FFMPEG_BINARY', 'ffmpeg-imageio') == 'ffmpeg-imageio':
    imageio.plugins.ffmpeg.download()
```

3) set path to binaries in `/site-packages/moviepy/config-defaults.py` line 53-54:

```
FFMPEG_BINARY = pathWithFilenameForDownloadedAndUnzipped_ffmpeg.exe ;
IMAGEMAGICK_BINARY =  ..\magick.exe"
```