# Python Windows 10 64bit - FFMPEG for trackpy

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, imagemagick, 64-bit, trackpy

Similar problem to '[Python Moviepy installation problems (windows 7x64)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50380974/python-moviepy-installation-problems-windows-7x64)' except the solution provided did not work.

I have windows 10, 64bit. Every time I attempt to run the following line of code:

```
frames = pims.Video('exp9_short.avi')
```

I get the blue Windows 10 error: This app can't run on your PC

as well as the Python error:

```
OSError: Could not load meta information
=== stderr ===

Access is denied.
```

I have tried multiple versions from 'https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/' to no avail.

I don't know if other image processing tools will work with trackpy, or if there are any alternatives to trackpy.

I would really appreciate some advice.

Comment: Just a thought. I do not know if relevant. But if either software needs ImageMagick (say to display the results or read input images) as per the solution in the link you posted, note that there are two version, IM 6 and IM 7. Be sure you installed the correct version for your system and software.

Comment: For ImageMagick binaries, see https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows and https://legacy.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows

Comment: I tried it with both dynamic and static win64 at 16 bits per pixel. Still the same result.

Comment: What about the difference between IM 6 and IM 7. Did you try both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by processing each image with OpenCV2

```
vid0 = cv2.VideoCapture('exp9_short.avi')

numfr = int(vid0.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))

for n1 in range(0,numfr-1):
    success,img = vid0.read(n1)         #read video frame by frame

    if n1==0:
        h, w, cols = img.shape          #image size
        fr=np.zeros([h,w,3,numfr-1])    #frames
        frgr=np.zeros([h,w,numfr-1])    #grayscale fr
        frgrbi=frgr                     #binarized frgr

    fr[:,:,:,n1]=img
    frgr[:,:,n1]=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```